# Extracting portion of the HTML page

Tags: php, css, html-parsing

Is it possible to extract a portion of a remote HTML page, and print it on another page, using PHP cURL, HTML DOM parser, or any other method, preserve the original formatting styles, images, tabs functioning?
For example, how to extract content of central column (with tabs and formatting, preserve the look of the original text), from http://ru.yahoo.com/?

As far as I understand, the script should process an external CSS, so that returned content has the same look as the original. What would be most appropriate way, if that's possible? If yes, an example would be highly appreciated. I looked several examples, but didn't find any solution for my case.

Comment: I have the feeling you want this for something kinda unethical. But well, how could I know.

Comment: Just thinking the same thing.

Comment: @Alexander. He probably want to copy the charity column...

Comment: Apart from a bit of scepticism about ethics, do you think of a special page or need this work for any page (i.e. a page that is created client-sided by JS)

Comment: @gdoron, yeah, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Well if I had to do it quickly (read: very dirty) I would do is this I think:

1. Pull the HTML from the remote server using standard PHP
2. Use the HTML that you <strike>stole</strike> took from the other site and add your own HTML to it down at the bottom.
3. Also add your own CSS to hide the html of the other site you don't want to be visible and style your own html.

Fiddle until it look okay enough. However: I think this will break the loading of the external JS files because of the same domain policy.

A nice approach would be this:

1. Pull the HTML from the remote server using standard PHP
2. Parse the HTML with some PHP HTML parser and strip out all external CSS and JS files and pull those files as well.
3. Use XPath to extract the parts that you need.
4. Create a new HTML document with your own HTML, the parts that you need, new links to your newly downloaded CSS and JS files. Also add your own CSS and JS to style the result.

You know: RSS was invented for this and if they don't provide an rss feed they most likely don't want you to get the content and post it on your own site. :P

Comment: That stole-took should gain you the humor badge! **+1**

Comment: @Gordon thanks for editing post. I'm sorry if my question seemed unethical and caused a debate. I dont mean to steal the contents, and it's public anyway, and they feed content from external newspapers too. I am looked solution for any page with content like this, that was just a nice example. Yes, I know RSS invented for this, and there is method to create RSS from any content, also.